# How to check that only one value of my dictionary is filled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

How can I check that my dict contains only one value filled ?

I want to enter in my condition only if the value is the only one in my dict and of this type (in my example "test2") of my dict.

For now I have this if statement

```py
my_dict = {}
my_dict["test1"] = ""
my_dict["test2"] = "example"
my_dict["test3"] = ""
my_dict["test4"] = ""
if my_dict["test2"] and not my_dict["test1"] and not my_dict["test3"] and not my_dict["test4"]:
   print("inside")
```

I would like to find a better, classy and "pep8" way to achieve that

Any ideas ?

Comment: So you want to know if the value of a key is equal to `""`?

Comment: what's the logic behind checking only one value?

Comment: It's an ExpertSystem so it had a lot of ruled based statement. So if only test2 is active it does one thing if more test are active it does other stuff

Comment: @Raphaël got your point, please check my answer below.!

Comment: What if only, say, `test3`, is active ? I mean, do you peculiarly want to check for `test2` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check every value for truthiness, there's no way around that, e.g.

```
if sum(1 for v in my_dict.values() if v) == 1:
    print('inside')
```

Comment: assumes that all falsy values, i.e., `None`, `0`, `False`, have to be considered as equivalent to `""`. Otherwise, you indirectly also make the assumption that all the values are strings.

Comment: @keepAlive yes, and other falsy values, could do `if not v == ""`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` as below to check how many values are there in the dictionary.

```
if len(list(filter(None, my_dict.values()))) == 1:
    print("inside")
```

Comment: less memory efficient than some ways since you build the entire list of values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check if there's only one pair in dictionary after removing the empty values.

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict["test1"] = ""
my_dict["test2"] = "example"
my_dict["test3"] = ""
my_dict["test4"] = ""

my_dict={key:val for key,val in my_dict.items() if val} 
if len(my_dict)==1:
    print("inside")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your values are strings, what about

```
ref_key = "test2"
if ''.join(my_dict.values()) == my_dict[ref_key]:
   print("inside")
```

... since it ***looks like*** you have a precise key in mind (when you do `if my_dict["test2"]`). Otherwise, my answer is (twice) less general than (some) others'.

Comment: also assumes all the values are strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another flavour (without loops):

```
data = list(my_dict.values())
if data.count('') + 1 == len(data):
    print("Inside")
```